# Xamarin.Auth.AccountStore.Create not found

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, android-keystore

I am trying to use this guide with Xamarin.Forms DependencyService:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/

When ever I try to call a method from my PCL project (say for instance DoCredentialsExist() (check the github code sample) i'm getting this error:

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Xamarin.Auth.AccountStore.Create' not found.

I can't help but think there must be some setup I need to do in order for they android keystore to work properly?

Comment: How did you install the xamarin forms oauth? [Can not install the component issue](https://github.com/Bigsby/Xamarin.Forms.OAuth/issues/9) is still there.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this error but I'm not able to reconstruct which step exactly solved the issue for me. But these are the steps I did:

**Steps:**

- Builded my solution trough msbuild in the console and first cleaned everything: `msbuild /t:clean` and then `msbuild` → I got a few errors in the Console and solved these
- Updated my Xamarin.Auth package to the newest version in the Android and the PCL project.
- Updated Xamarin.Forms to the newest stable release
- Deleted obj/bin folders of all projects then rebuild